# Excel File size issue. while poi write

Tags: java, apache-poi, drools

I am writing to excel using apache POI and getting data into it fine. now I have to pass this excel as input to drools project. 
Issue is: if I provide the exact excel it is giving me error 
if I open it and save it then it is working fine.

I was wondering what is happening with excel by opening it and saving.

what I observed is: excel when it created : 6 kbs
after opening and saving simply then it's showing : 27kbs

drools is accepting 27kbs excel but throwing runtime exception with 6kb excel.

have been searching for solution in java. kindly advice.

Comment: Recheck your excel creation code as that code should create excel of size 27kbs.

Comment: but 6kbs Excel I am not missing single line of data. only issue with size.

Comment: Opening the file and saving it increases the size, this means the MS Excel is adding/modifying some file related attributes that needs to be handled by the code only. After this code change opening and saving the file should not increase the size. I guess in that way the problem can be solved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understood there  is a issue with data format but not with code. when we remove we lines of data for particular columns it's working fine with out issues.